# How to call a @helper function inside a href tag

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is the function created inside my razor view.

```
     @helper deleteEnquires(){
          @foreach (var items in Model)
          {
             @Html.Action("DeleteEnquires", "CoursePlan", new { id = items.ID})
        }
     }
```

How do I can call this function using a < a href> tag. When I click the link, this method should call.

Comment: you are really new to MVC Razor views aren't you?

Comment: Of course @vendettamit. I want to learn these stuffs.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I Filtering my model records. I want to delete all model records when I click on a link or a button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@helper` for this. Just use `@Html.ActionLink` helper

```
@foreach (var items in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Click Here to Delete", "DeleteEnquires", "CoursePlan", new { id = items.ID})
}
```

`href` property will be like this (depending on your `RouteConfig`) `/CoursePlan/DeleteEnquires/33`